# Orchard : DateTime Field doesn't appear in search index

Tags: orchardcms

I have created one content part say News which is attachable, having one property of type DateTime 
I have attached this content part to one content type. 
in content type I have set "Include in index" for my DateTime field of content part.

now i have created one index say NewsIndex. 
Set this newsIndex in content type (Published Version)

Rebuild index. 
now when i go to Settings->Search, I am not able to see my DateTime field check box over there.

I am using Orchard version : 1.10.1.0

I have tried above situation by both way.. (From admin dashboard and using Code)

Facing this issue since 5 day, trying a lot but not able to get success. Really needed help on this.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, your DateTime-Field is a property on your custom ContentPart. I'd try to either swap that property out for an `Orchard.Fields.DateTimeField` or otherwise use the OnIndexing-Override of your parts handler to index your property manually.